# Analytic information about single visitor (GA?)

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I would like to get information about single visitor, who finished the order in eshop. I would like to collect all the usefull dimensional information (utm_campaign, returning visitor, referrer, source, medium etc.) and save it to the current order in my website. The API would maybe allow get these information, but it's not realtime. There is a delay 3-4 hours before the information about single page analysis is updated. (I would have uique URL after finishing the order - with ID of order - this would help me to find out the visitor in GA).

Is there any posibility to do it through GA? Or any other option? I need these information realtime saved at order in my website. Thanks for advices.

Answer (score 0):

The RealTime API doesn't allow you to request eCommerce data, you need to wait the 6-24 hours before the information is available to the core reporting API.   You could send a custom event when they are done placing the order then retrieve that from the RealTime API.